# ExtJS HTML load googlemap failed

Tags: google-maps, extjs4

```
var layout = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    // title: 'Border Layout', //no title will be blank
    layout: 'border',
    items: [{
        title: 'Message List',
        region: 'south', // position for region
        xtype: 'panel',
        height: 100,
        split: true, // enable resizing
        collapsible: true,
        margins: '0 5 5 5',
        collapsed: true
    }, tree, {
        html: '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAZx1jmE9yB533ED9suD13buyd0pEfmTzI&sensor=false&dummy=.js">
                </script> 
                <script type="text/javascript">
                init();
                function init() {
                var googleMapOptions = 
                {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.5267, -1.13330),
                zoom: 16, 
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),googleMapOptions);
                }</script>
                <body>
                <div id="map_canvas" style="width:600px; height:400px"></div>
                </body>',
         renderTo: Ext.getBody()
     }],
     renderTo: Ext.getBody()
     // get the body and display Layout at there
});
```

but i m using http://jsfiddle.net/anthor/ufTpN/ are work well, when paste in ExrJS then can't load google map. Why?

PS: I don't want to use Gmappanel and No Iframe, because I want to add marker on this page

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: @CyrilPangilinan nothing, no error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I advise you to use Ext.ux.GMapPanelView basic implementation.

> P/S:i don't want to use Gmappanel and No Iframe,because i want to add marker on this page

**You can add a marker** very simple, look at the code:

```
 addMarker: function(marker) {
    marker = Ext.apply({
        map: this.gmap
    }, marker);

    if (!marker.position) {
        marker.position = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.lat, marker.lng);
    }
    var o =  new google.maps.Marker(marker);
    Ext.Object.each(marker.listeners, function(name, fn){
        google.maps.event.addListener(o, name, fn);    
    });
    return o;
}
```

So you can even add listeners to it.

What you are trying to do in the code snippet (example):

```
{
  html: '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAZx1jmE9yB533ED9suD13buyd0pEfmTzI&sensor=false&dummy=.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  init();

  function init() {
   var googleMapOptions = {
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.5267, -1.13330),
       zoom: 16, 
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),googleMapOptions);
  }
  </script>
  **<body>**
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:600px; height:400px"></div>
  **</body>**',

 **renderTo: Ext.getBody()**
}
```

Sorry, absolutely is wrong. Adding body tag, rendering to body being under the panel container `Ext.panel.Panel`, which itself renders its items and etc, this looks that you know not much about the ext's internals and how it works.

You are trying to do something similar that guys from sencha propose to use via basic and very, very simple ux implementation. You can extend it even further.

Just take a look at:

[GMapPanelView example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/window/gmap.html)
also look at the source just to see where googleapis are plugged (you can extend the gmap view loading it async if you want)

[GMapPanelView source code](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/ux/GMapPanel.js)

[example source](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/window/gmap.js)

An very **simple example** with layout border, you have used. In the west region you can find add button, press it to add marker.

[**Gmap usage, jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nbabinski/r8Sga/3/) (just an example; don't write actual code this way)

Do not be afraid to look at the source!

Good Luck ;)

Comment: ,u can try to add a InfoWindow in the GmapPanel, because GMapPanel infowindow can't close

Comment: have you tried http://jsfiddle.net/nbabinski/r8Sga/3/ ?
from the code you posted, you are trying to do the same thing that "gmappanel" does.

Comment: i have no idea how to add a infowindow in your coding,when clicked marker will pop up infowindow,and my marker are dynamic marker

Comment: @ChinYe "i have no idea how to add a infowindow in your coding" this is not the topic of the question. I just answered to your question. You have the source code of the GMapPanel, the code is short. Should be noticed that `gmap` property of the panel reference to the google map object (createMap method) and others things. Having reference to gmap you can do with it what you want.
But it is better to extend the GMapPanel and add all required functionality in it. Below is the link to another example adding `google.maps.InfoWindow` http://jsfiddle.net/nbabinski/ChjbS/1/ just simple/stupid

Comment: How to implement in MVC?where i should write that code